# tinymce setting custom format on a span node

Tags: tinymce

I am trying this for several hours now

How do I apply a custom format on a 'span' node.

This is what I using:

Tinymce version 3.5.8

code:

tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.apply('highlight1', {}, this);

Error on Firebug:

TypeError: aA.parentNode is null
[Break On This Error]

..."next"]()){if(q.nodeType===3&&q.nodeValue.length>0){o=q;r=B?q.nodeValue.length:0...

I read here that apparently there is an issue:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Formatter.apply

is this a known issue and is there any work around.